# Memory continuously increase in Instrumentation even with ARC

Tags: memory-management, ios7, automatic-ref-counting

I am creating an application with ARC enabled and iOS 7 only. My all properties are properly marked as weak and all strong variables are marked as nil where I need it.

When I run my application with Instruments I found that memory allocation is continous increasing. When I go to any screen the memory increases (approximate 2 MB). When I pop that view the memory gets down to only few KBs. I don't know what happening.

while poping a view I am using following:

**UPDATE:**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        CGRect newFrame = aSideMenu.view.frame;
        newFrame.origin = SIDE_MENU_VIEW_ORIGIN_FINAL;
        [aSideMenu.view setFrame:newFrame];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [sender setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}];
```

Here I am using `aSideMenu` in block. `aSideMenu` is strong variable. Do you think I need to create it's weak reference and use?

```
__weak id aWeak = aSideMenu;
```

and use this aWeak instead of aSideMenu?

Also In few block I am using:

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:....nil];
```

Should I pass weak reference of `dict' too?

I am not sure if this is the reason. Please help me to track the issue. Also let me know if anything else needs to add in this question for better solution.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the which is inside this block...? It is possible you are referencing which should not and it retains some object... If you are accessing self in block make shore your creating weak pointer to self before entering in block.

Comment: Yes you should make weak reference for any strong pointers in side block. But weak pointers can be nil if object is deallocated, so make strong reference to weak pointer inside the block and check for nil before using it. For dictionary, if its instance variable or property then yes, if its method local then use block operator, and if its in side block then use it as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great if you paste your code also. Without code I can just give you some tips.
Like never try to access strong pointer of self in block. Before entering in a block create weak pointer of self.

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
```

and then use `weakSelf` inside the block.

Better also test your app for unbounded memory growth, where allocated memory never get chance to dealloct, you can take footprints by using Allocation instrument.

**Update:**

1. YES because you are calling setter method on strong pointer, it will retain it. You have to make them __weak or __block if they are shared.
   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1
2. After having some more code, I want to make some thing more clear about the referenceing in block.
   Memory issue may arrise when you reference some strong pointer inside block, as block will not let them deallocat, as they have valid reference, this is the major reason of memory issues. For that we have we create a weak pointer by using `__weak id` so I will not create a retian cycle. 
   But there is another issue if object have no other vaild reference, It will be deallocated and `weak` reference will be nil and it can cause a crash.

So good practice is to create a strong reference to weak in side the block and check for the nil.

Comment: Might want to add this to your answer. To be more specific how to avoid strong reference cycles when using blocks. although your answer covers it well. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Comment: @C_X all the IBOutlets I use are defined as `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet <ClassName> iVarName;` So this will not be retained by blocks as are already weak.. Am I right?